# Sort and Filter Rich Text

Tags: list, filter, rich-text, sorting

i have a sharepoint list with a few rich text columns but in the view the headlines of these doesnt have the button to sort or filter them like all other non rich text columns have.
is there a way to enable such features for rich text?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why they are disabled is because the rich text fields contains html formatting, and will by default always be wrapped inside two hidden div tags and making the functions useless.

Comment: not just rich text, event plain text column type of 'multiple line of text' column is not sortable. I think they are saved as ntext in DB.

Comment: You got a good point there!

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple Value fields** and **Multiple lines of text fields** in SharePoint list cannot be sorted, its the default behaviour of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 1 line text column
create a workflow and set a variable to the multiline you wish to sort
set the 1 line text column to the variable

you can now sort the multiline column by sorting the 1 line text column